# Google Glass : imageView fullscreen?

Tags: android, imageview, google-glass, google-gdk

Using Google Glass, I would like to know if it possible to have an imageView which take all the space ?

With the following code, I have always something like 10px all around the image :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayoutImage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0sp"
android:layout_margin="0sp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check your layout.xml file in which this imageview is there. From the parent layout remove all the android:padding tags, which reference to dimen.xnl file.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't post my entire xml, I edited my question

Comment: Set your linear layout's width and height as 640 and 360 px..

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi Good idea but it didn't work, even using "sp" or "dp" as unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you don't have padding or theme, your view is probably already fullscreen. That mysterious extra space is not a part of Glass screen or not usable.

Try this:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
```

You'll see that the image from the frame buffer doesn't have that 10 px all around the image.

I am not sure about your case but that's what happened to me.

[image]

Comment: Yep you are probably right, there is some space, but it is not usable. You idea of screenshot show that the image is already fullscreen, thanks.